# Splitting columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Greetings to everyone!

I've just registered to the site in search for an answer; I've been browsing the questions here before, and I'm done with mostly everything I need to do, with one exception.

I've been trying to look for answers, one of them partially worked, but the problem is still unsolved. I'm really sorry if it's been asked before (although from my search I doubt it, or I probably did it wrong).

Basically, I have a table in this format:

```
Onething.10.20g  || A

Anotherthing.20.15g ||  B
```

... (It goes on and on, but is similar.)

What I'd need to do is converting it to the following format using VBA only:

```
Onething   ||  10  ||   20g  ||    A

Anotherthing || 20  ||   15g  ||    B
```

What I managed to do somehow was basically something like this:

```
Onething.10.20g   ||    10

Anotherthing.20.15g  ||  20
```

Which obviously shows to me that the trail is not exactly wrong, but something's not quite right, either.

I can't really paste the code right here, either, but a little later I could be able to do that.

Thank you in advance and I'm sorry for any inconvenience I might cause!

Comment: It will be very difficult for anyone to help you with your code until you have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 'double pipe' character means a new column then try the following.  Note that it will overwrite your original data.

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As String, constr As String
Dim stCol As Long, stRow As Long, endRow As Long

stCol = 2
stRow = 1
endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, stCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For c = stRow To endRow
        constr = Cells(c, stCol).Value & "." & Cells(c, stCol).Offset(0, 1).Value
        arr() = Split(constr, ".")
        Range(Cells(c, stCol), Cells(c, UBound(arr, 1) + stCol)) = arr
    Next c
End Sub
```